# Differences between simulator build, device connected by cable build and ad hoc build iOS7

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios7, build, adhoc

App that i'm working on works without problems in simulator, also when built from Xcode on iPhone connected with cable.

When i create an ad hoc build and install the app, 99% percent off the app works without problems, only one controller fails and crashes the app when i press the button which calls a method for sending data to server and saving data to the database.

I have 15 other similar controllers, and all are working without problems.

Is there any significant difference between builds for the simulator, build for a iPhone connected via cable and ad hoc build?

Comment: The simulator runs a x86 binary in the simulator which call the OSX methods. The debug version (the one you talk about running with the cable) is running as none optimized. Which the AdHoc version is. Your best get the crash log for the AdHoc version from you phone and symbolize them to see what is making your app crash.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to get that log, i was wondering if i could get some kind of info from the app. 

I tried some alertviews with variable info, but it seems as if app crashes without entering the method, so i didn't get anything from it.

Comment: Just connect your device and open the Xcode organizer, here you will see your device and be able to access the crash logs. Other which TestFlight may be of help.

Comment: Maybe Xcode Organizer?

Thanks :)